# Laravel how to store user visited product

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am working a eCommerce application using laravel framework 5.2. my client want to show the wishlist of product . user visited product add in wishlist . i want to do the work in cookie but i cant find the way how it store and destroy and modified in cookie

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solve this problem , i made a middleware  where i get the product ID , then find it is valid product ID , if valid then store in cookie

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        if ($request->hasCookie('visited_product')) {
            $info = Cookie::get('visited_product');
            if (!in_array($request->product_id, $info)) {
                $info[] = $request->product_id;
                return $response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('visited_product', $info));
            }
            return $response;

        } else {
            $product_list = [];
            $product_list[] = $request->product_id;
            return $response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('visited_product', $product_list));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Read the [cookie documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#cookies) on the Laravel website.

To quote the Laravel documentation directly:

```
// read a cookie value
$value = $request->cookie('name');

// write a new cookie
$response->withCookie('name', 'value', $minutes);

// write a cookie that never expires:
$response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('name', 'value'));
```

Comment: I'd like to know too. The question asks how to store/destroy cookies using Laravel. All of the information related to that question is available on the URL provided in the question. Short of copy/pasting the contents of that page into this page, there's nothing more to be said.

Comment: why u copy paste from the documentation , this info i already know but the documentation is not clear enough

Comment: Can you explain more clearly exactly what you do not understand, or what exactly you're trying to do? The Laravel documentation is quite clear on how to store and retrieve cookie values. Try posting some sample code that you're having difficulties getting to work.